# CSS Framework Issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to develop a easy web site, I'm not very good at web developing, but I tried and the result was this : http://www.pes.herobo.com.

As you can see the page isn't very good and if you try to re-size it the result is awful. In addition, I need the website is accessible from mobile devices such as smart phones and tablets.

Cause of these issues I've decided to use a CSS framework. I found very interesting bootstrap ( If I understood well it would be developed by Twitter ), so I have  more or less rewritten all my website using it and its system.  The result has been much better the website resizes in the correct way and if you look at it on phones the look is perfect.

But I'm still wondering how I should use the image in the correct way, I want they to resize as all elements inside the web page, so I've adopted this solution, and I would like to know if it is correct.

The CSS class `imagine` is :

```
.imagine {
    width:100%; 
    height:auto; 
}
```

The code is:

```
   <div class="row"> 
            <div class="span8" style="position:relative">
            <img src="img/image.jpg"  class="imagine" style="z-index:0 id="img_oxf">
            <img src="img/site_under_construction.png" class="imagine" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:30%;z-index:1"; id="img_under_constr">
            <img src="img/blue_strap.png" class="imagine" ">    
            </div> 
            <div class="span4"> 
            <div id="main_paragraph">   
            </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your HTML is terribly invalid.  Invalid HTML will lead to unpredictable results and inconsistent rendering across browsers.  Start with valid HTML before trying to solve other issues.

---

This is wrong...

```
<img src="img/image.jpg"  class="imagine" style="z-index:0 id="img_oxf">
```

You're missing a closing quote on `style` which may make the browser think `id="img_oxf` is supposed to be inside `style`.  It should be...

```
<img src="img/image.jpg"  class="imagine" style="z-index:0;" id="img_oxf">
```

---

And this is wrong...

```
<img src="img/site_under_construction.png" class="imagine" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:30%;z-index:1"; id="img_under_constr">
```

You have a semicolon between HTML attributes.  It should be...

```
<img src="img/site_under_construction.png" class="imagine" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:30%;z-index:1;" id="img_under_constr">
```

---

And this is wrong...

```
<img src="img/blue_strap.png" class="imagine" ">
```

You have an extra quote `"` which may cause the browser to think your class is called `imagine"` instead of `imagine`. It should be...

```
<img src="img/blue_strap.png" class="imagine">
```

---

And you seem to be missing a closing `</div>` tag someplace.

Comment: yes yes.... It has been  reporting error!! there isn't specific error,  but i would like to know if I'm doing the right things.

Comment: @GiuseppePes, Having invalid HTML is definitely not _"doing the right things"_.  With the way it's written, you can't even be sure your CSS is being applied.

Comment: you are perfectly right, but the majority of them is reporting error, I put here the html code only to give a Idea! The most impart thing for me was the class to manage the images..

Comment: @GiuseppePes, But your HTML can cause your class to not be applied... see the third item in my answer.